# Different behavior during Nuxt 3 SSR call

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm trying to call an api throughout a http proxy, which looks somewhat like this for my own Nuxt 3 api endpoint.

file: `server/api/custom.ts`

```
import axios from 'axios';
import httpsProxyAgent from 'https-proxy-agent'; // running on version 5.0.1

axios.get("https://some-api.com/foo/bar", {
  httpsAgent: httpsProxyAgent({
            host: process.env.PROXY_HOST!,
            port: parseInt(process.env.PROXY_PORT!),
        });
})
```

Accessing this url directly works.

`http://localhost:3000/api/custom`

However, when running within a page and using `useAsyncData` against my own endpoint, I run into a protocol issue.

So this ...

```
await useAsyncData(async () => {
    return (await $fetch('/api/custom'));
});
```

Now results in this ...

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"`

This only happens because the proxy is forwarding the requested url through `http` and the third-party api is redirecting to `https`. So naturally, using a `https` proxy would solve the issue. However, that's not possible. On the other hand, accessing the exact same endpoint directly through my custom api (without running a server side rendered page using `useAsyncData`) it works. So it seems like there's a difference between Nuxt 3 api usage as well as the SSR environment.

Hint: This issue just came up recently when we migrated the application from Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3. So basically, the exact same code was behaving differently and just worked in the past.

Long story short: Is there any possible fix for that?